# Error Processing Request - Oracle Application Express (APEX)

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a Master-Detail Interactive Grid page in Oracle Application Express.  Occasionally, users get the error message "Error Processing Request" when they attempt to save changes to the interactive grids.  The users don't see any other detail on the error (including the code for the error).  In those instances, there are no obvious problems with the data being entered (no mandatory fields missing, validations that would fail, etc).  I am unable to reproduce these errors myself.  I suspect that the errors may be caused by some sort of connectivity problem, but I have no way to verify this.  Is anybody aware of the cause (or common causes) of this error?

Comment: Which Apex version do you use? On 4.2.2 it is a known bug and there's a patch for it (available on My Oracle Support).

Comment: I'm on 5. I found the specific problem  (thanks to RomeuBraga for the advice) but still don't have a solution (see my question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265868/ora-01403-no-data-found-when-working-with-master-detail-ig-in-oracle-apex))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, but a tip to try to find more information on the "monitor activity".

1 - Go to "monitor activity"

[image]

2 - Click on "By View"

3 - Try to find in the report, filtering in the error column, some occurrence of this error.

[image]

4 - Check if is there a link in the "debug id" column; it will take you to more details about page execution; see if you find any error code or some other useful information ...