# ORA-01403: No Data Found when working with Master-Detail IG in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, master-detail, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

In Oracle APEX 5.1, I have an Interactive Grid Master-Detail page. The following series of steps (which users sometimes take) creates an unhandled exception (ORA-01403: no data found).

1. User creates an invalid record in the master section and a corresponding record in the detail section.
2. User attempts to save (row processing) and receives error due to invalid master record.
3. Without deleting the invalid master record, user activates filters which remove invalid master record.
4. User makes (valid) additions/modifications to other records
5. User attempts to save.
6. User receives an error (ORA-01403: no data found).

I believe the problem is that the detail records for the invalid (now removed) master record are still being processed when the user saves.  However, there is no way for the user to access those records, nor can I figure out how to remove them automatically (the ORA 01403 error occurs prior to and halts page processing and validation as far as I can tell).

Any suggestions for how to prevent this, handle the error, or enable users to correct this error would be appreciated.

Here's the backtrace for the error, if it's helpful:

- error_backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_INTERACTIVE_GRID", line 7640
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_INTERACTIVE_GRID", line 7819
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_INTERACTIVE_GRID", line 7850
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_INTERACTIVE_GRID", line 8990
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_REGION_NATIVE", line 3101
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2146
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 3006
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW", line 3190
  ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW", line 5544

Comment: Enable Debug mode and repeat steps you've described. Once you hit the NO-DATA-FOUND, view debug results, You should be able to see which SELECT is responsible for the error (or, at least, I hope so).

Comment: The problematic SELECT statement is in APEX's built-in Interactive Grid code (see above error backtrace, which is from the debug results).  I'd strongly prefer not to attempt to alter the built-in code (although if someone has a straightforward solution that involves altering it, I'd implement it)

Comment: I wouldn't modify Apex code either. As of the error stack ... useless, at least from my point of view. I hoped for some SELECT statement you wrote, which could be modified in order to avoid the error. The way it is now, I don't have any other ideas, sorry.

Comment: At the end of this page you can find some common bugs in IG (
There is a description of a similar bug on that page ...):

https://github.com/mgoricki/orclapex-ig-cheat-sheet